# How to convert Android.mk to CMake.txt?

Tags: android, cmake, native, ndk-build

This is how my Android.mk file looks like. What is the equivalent CMakeLists.txt? I am struggling to find libhardware in CMake. Any ideas?

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtestLed
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := testled.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=  $(call include-path-for, libhardware)/hardware
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += \
    libandroid_runtime \
    libcutils \
    liblog \
    libhardware \

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_VENDOR_MODULE := true
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: **Which line** in file `Android.mk` you have failed to convert to `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: It happens to me.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libhardware. This line.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

the line you mentioned would be 
target_link_libraries(testLed hardware)